# How to set up a dockerfile properly for Spring Boot with Maven?

Tags: spring-boot, docker

Based on [the Spring Boot Docker guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/), I set up the dockerfile as the following

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:8-jdk-hotspot
ARG JAR_FILE=*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "application.jar"]
```

where the jar file is in the same directory as the dockerfile.

And I have a docker compose file as

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    image: 'my-app:latest'
    build:
      context: .
     container_name: app
     depends_on:
      - my-postgres
     environment:
       - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/mydb
       - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=user1
       - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=user.1
       - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update

  my-postgres:
    image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user1
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=user.1
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      # copy the sql script to create tables
      - ./sql/baseline.sql:/dshocker-entrypoint-initdb.d/baseline.sql
```

After building the docker image, I run the docker compose. The app isn't up though. It doesn't show up with "docker ps", but "docker ps -all".

The command shown with its docker entry,

```
java -jar application.jar
```

won't start up the app because the app requests one or two configuration files, but

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

does.

I, however, haven't seen the line

```
 ENTRYPOINT ["mvn", "spring-boot:run"]
```

in a dockerfile yet.

How to set it up properly then?

I also run

```
mvn spring-boot:build-image
```

after upgrade the Spring Boot version. And although the docker compose command can be run, but the application container exited soon. The command is

```
/cnb/process/web
```

I haven't seen it before.

Comment: But if your app has configuration files it doesn’t look like you’re copying them into the image or mounting them in your docker compose file.